# Form handling in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm quite new to spring, I trying to create a form that will create a new Item then save it to my MYSQL database. Attached here is the whole controller class and the html form.

```js
package com.emil.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import com.emil.model.Item;
import com.emil.repositories.ItemRepository;

@Controller
public class ItemController{
  @Autowired
  private ItemRepository itemRepository;


  @RequestMapping(path="/items", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getItems(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("items", itemRepository.findAll());
    return "items";
  }

  @RequestMapping(path="/item", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getItem(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("item", new Item());
    return "item";
  }

  @RequestMapping(path="/item", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void addNewItem(@ModelAttribute Item item){
    Item newItem = new Item();
    newItem.setItemDesc(item.getItemDesc());

  }

}
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjIXy.png)

[html form snippet code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFuVZ.png)

Comment: does your form really have as `action` parameter `/item`?

Comment: like this ? <form action="#" th:action="@{/item}" th:object="${item}" method="post">

Comment: ah, as I see you are using Thymeleaf as View technology. I can't help you, sorry. Try this: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html especially the Chapter 6.

Comment: Can you recomend me another view technology to make my life easirer? :-)

Comment: I was using Wicket and I am satisfied with it, but I really don't know Thymeleaf. Maybe it is better, but I really don't know.

Comment: Do you see any mistake I made within my Controller class? I can't really tell if the problem lies within my view or my controller.

Comment: Try to remove @ModelAttribute annotation.

Comment: Tried it, with and without that annotation, no error page but its not saving in my database. lol.

Comment: sure it is not, you did not call your `itemRepository` in `addNewItem()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i was able to make it work  @RequestMapping(path="/item", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void addNewItem(@ModelAttribute Item item){
    itemRepository.save(item);

  }

Comment: Well I am happy, that your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you probably have an error in the submitted item, a required field might be null or a submitted value cannot be parsed.
To see the actual error, you could use something like

```
@RequestMapping(path="/item", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void addNewItem(@ModelAttribute Item item, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.toString()));
        // Handle error
    }
    Item newItem = new Item();
    newItem.setItemDesc(item.getItemDesc());
}
```

If you know how to debug (if you don't you should try to learn it :-)), you could put a breakpoint on line one and inspect the BindingResult.